# Attaching a file to email through Xamarin android app with Android API 30 (Android 11)

Tags: xamarin.android, android-permissions, android-11

I have a Xamarin android app which attaches a log file to Email. With Android 10, this was working fine. But when I try this on Android 11 phones, it says " Unable to attach a file" in the email application.
Then, I came across this blog explaining the package visibility in Android 11, and the changes that needs to be done
[https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-11-package-visibility/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H0Iz.png)

SO, I made changes accordingly by adding this in my manifest file

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

I do have permission for reading and writing external storage files.

Below is the code, which I use for attaching logs and sending it through email.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);

        if ((ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ysiCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted) &&
            (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ysiCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted))
        {
            ysiMainActivity activity = (ysiMainActivity)ysiCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;

            if (activity.GetExternalFilesDir(null) != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath))
            {
                string sFilePath = Path.Combine(activity.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath, "MobileAppLogs.log");
                if (!File.Exists(sFilePath))
                {
                    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Create);
                    fileStream.Dispose();
                }
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(sFilePath, false))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(logs);
                }

                Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(sFilePath);
                file.SetReadable(true, false);
                Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);

                intent.SetData(Uri.Parse("mailto:"));
                intent.SetType("message/rfc822");
                intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "Logs");
                intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uri);

                ysiCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Send email"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Even after adding the manifest changes, I still cannot attach the logs to email.
Am i still missing something.

[image]

Comment: use fileprovider uri instead of Uri.fromFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android&WT.mc_id=docs-xamarinblog-jamont) to achieve this.

The `Email` class enables an application to open the default email application with a specified information including subject, body, and recipients.

When we check part [File Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android&WT.mc_id=docs-xamarinblog-jamont#file-attachments),we could find that:

> This feature enables an app to email files in email clients on the
> device. Xamarin.Essentials will automatically detect the file type
> (MIME) and request the file to be added as an attachment. Every email
> client is different and may only support specific file extensions, or
> none at all.

Here is a sample of writing text to disk and adding it as an email attachment:

```
var message = new EmailMessage
{
    Subject = "Hello",
    Body = "World",
};

var fn = "Attachment.txt";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

message.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(file));

await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
```

**Note:**

If your project's Target Android version is set to Android 11 (R API 30) you must update your Android Manifest with queries that are used with the new [package visibility requirements](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility).

Open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file under the `Properties` folder and add the following inside of the `manifest` node:

```
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

For more details,check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android&WT.mc_id=docs-xamarinblog-jamont.